# Does the "procedure" of getting a value from an array has a name?

Tags: c++, arrays, call, procedure

I would like to know if the "procedure" of getting a value from an array has a name (for example, when you do this:

```
array[3] // this will get the value from index '4'
```

(in C++), does that procedure of getting the value has a name?)

I'm sorry if this is very well explained. I tried to search in Google for something, but I could not find anything with my words.

Comment: I thought the term was "accessing".  As in, "this is how you access the fourth element of the array"

Comment: I guess that's it, does anyone has an idea if that name "accessing" is right?

Answer (score 6):

It's called the *subscripting operator*. It's overloadable, but when used on an array or pointer, `a[n]` has the same meaning as `*(a + n)`.

The name comes presumably from mathematics, where a vector* is written as *v* = (*v*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *v*<sub>*n*</sub>), and so *v*<sub>*i*</sub> de­notes the *i*<sup>th</sup> element.

<sub>*) Unless you're a relativist, but those aren't allowed near computers. If they were, they'd shout "1-form" at you.</sub>

Comment: That's what it is, but not what the procedure of doing `a[n]` is called. I don't think there is one, save "subscripting".

Comment: @Kerrek, I don't think that's what I meant. What I'm trying to ask is the procedure of getting a value from an array, not the name of that thing you use to get a value from the array.

Comment: @Anderl: The standard says "subscripting" in 5.2.1, and just says "the expression `x[i]` [...] is equivalent to `*(x+i)`" in 8.3.4/8. I'm not sure what else you have in mind - do you have an analogous example?

Comment: @Anderl: Further more, the container part of the standard library doesn't name the operation, either, and just describes its effect in a similar way to the effect on arrays. The `operator[]` is listed under "element access", though.

Comment: I mean, just like we call it "calling a function" when we do for example "print( "heya" );", I'd like to know if there is a specific name for getting a value from an array too, not the name of the operator we use to do it. Not sure if that's you're trying to say..

Comment: @Anderl: Well, both `()` and `[]` appear in the standard as "postfix expressions", the former called "function call" and the latter "subscripting". Evaluating a function call expression is commonly referred to as "calling a function", but there's no equivalent for the subscripting expression in the standard, which just says that evaluating the expression `E1[E2]` is identical to `*(E1 + E2)`. However, "accessing an element of an array" is perfectly acceptable language.